.htaccess mod_rewrite - How to redirect both: "/page.html" and "/page/" to: "/page"?
I need some help with my .htaccess file.
I've been messing with it for about a week but cannot get it to work..
I've scoured the web for solutions but nothing really addresses my case.
In general, typing: website.com/info.html?page=12 should show: website.com/info/12
and the other way around: website.com/info/12 should serve: website.com/info.html?page=12.
Analogically, without the QUERY_STRING part:
website.com/info.html should show: website.com/info
and website.com/info should serve: website.com/info.html.
However!
website.com/info/ (only when followed by nothing) should redirect to: website.com/info.
How can I achieve this?
It should be simple but I cannot get my head around it yet..
Any tips greatly appreciated!
UPDATE:
Thanks for the answers and comments. It certainly shed some light on the subject. I'm almost there...
For starters, if anyone has trouble understanding regex these tools helped me immensely:
https://regexr.com
https://regex101.com
And a similar one for testing .htaccess files:
https://htaccess.madewithlove.com
Some clarification:
I need general .html hiding for all the pages but only one specific redirection from /info/ (there's no dir with this name) to /info.
I read ?page=12 parameter with JS window.location.search but I don't think it matters since I can replicate the error on a page without it.
Now, my .htaccess file looks like that:
RewriteEngine on

# Externally redirect: "/info.html?page=YYY" to: "/info/YYY" - WORKS
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=(\d+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^info\.html$ /info/%1? [NC,R=302,NE,L]

# Externally redirect: "/XXX.html" to: "/XXX" - WORKS
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(.+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,R=302,NE,L]

# Externally redirect: "/info/" to: "/info" - WORKS
RewriteRule ^info/$ /info [NC,R=302,L]

# Internally rewrite: "/info/YYY" to: "/info.html?page=YYY" - INTERNAL SERVER ERROR 
RewriteRule ^info/(\d+) /info.html?page=$1 [L]

# Internally rewrite: "/XXX" to: "/XXX.html" - WORKS
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [NC,L]

Just as stated in the comments, all work except the 4th one.
However, if I remove the 1st one, the 4th works.
What am I missing??

"I've been messing with it for about a week" - So, what have you tried? And what happens? Do you have any other directives in your .htaccess file? And I assume /info does not map to a physical directory? (There might be something more fundamental that is preventing this from working or just a minor tweak to existing rules.) Is it only for info, or do you need something more generic?

/info.html?page=12 - Taking a step backwards for a mo... how are you actually reading the URL parameter?


# Internally rewrite: "/info/YYY" to: "/info.html?page=YYY" - INTERNAL SERVER ERROR 
RewriteRule ^info/(\d+) /info.html?page=$1 [L]

I read ?page=12 parameter with JS window.location.search but I don't think it matters

Yes, it matters. You can't internally rewrite (on the server) to append a query string and expect client-side JS to be able to see that query string. The "internal rewrite" is entirely internal to the server. JS only sees the response sent back from the server, which does not include a query string (unless it was present on the initial request or you externally redirected to it).
Instead, you can internally rewrite a request for /info/12 to /info.html only (no query string) and use window.location.pathname to parse the URL-path (ie. /info/12) to extract the page from the second path segment (if any).
With regards to your "error". The first rule redirects the newly rewritten URL during the second pass by the rewrite engine, which would result in a redirect loop. The last rule could also result in an internal rewrite loop (internal server error) under certain conditions (since the condition using REQUEST_FILENAME is not testing the same thing as REQUEST_URI). You also need to ensure that MultiViews is disabled in this scenario, as this will otherwise conflict with your rewrites.
For some reason, you've resorted to using an empty query string (trailing ?) to discard the query string in the first rule. If you are on Apache 2.4 (as I would assume you are) then you should be using the QSD (Query String Discard) flag instead, as used in @arkascha's answer. Although your erroneous use of the NC flag on the condition that checks against -f makes me doubt your Apache version.
I assume that you are already linking to the canonical URL internally in your app, eg. /info/12 (not /info.html?page=12). And these redirects are only for SEO (if changing an existing URL structure) or users that might happen to type the old (non-canonical) URLs.
For example, try the following instead:
# Ensure that MultiViews is disabled
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine on

# Externally redirect: "/info.html?page=<num>" to: "/info/<num>"
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=(\d+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^info\.html$ /info/%1 [NC,QSD,R=302,L]

# Externally redirect: "/XXX.html" to: "/XXX"
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ /$1 [NC,R=302,L]

# Externally redirect: "/info/" to: "/info"
RewriteRule ^info/$ /info [NC,R=302,L]

# Internally rewrite: "/info/<num>" to: "/info.html"
RewriteRule ^info/\d+$ info.html [END]

# Internally rewrite: "/XXX" to: "/XXX.html" if it exists
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.html -f
RewriteRule (.+) $1.html [END]

I've used END (requires Apache 2.4) on the last two rules to prevent a second loop by the rewrite engine, which would otherwise result in a redirect loop.
Also note the addition of the end-of-string anchor ($) on the original regex ^info/(\d+), otherwise you are allowing URLs of the form /info/12<anything>.
I've removed the slash prefix on the substitution strings of the two rewrites as we are rewriting to a file-path, not a URL-path. By rewriting to a URL-path (slash prefix) you are (unnecessarily) forcing the rewrite engine to remap the URL to the filesystem.
You have to be careful when checking against THE_REQUEST as this also includes the query string (if any), which you would need to avoid when checking for .html.
And, as mentioned, you will need to use window.location.pathname in your client-side JS instead to parse the page number (if any) from the requested URL.
Note that this can be further optimised/simplified if we know more about your system/URL structure. For instance, are you only dealing with URLs in the document root, as in your example, or are you also expecting /foo/bar/baz as well? Do your URLs contain dots? (That would otherwise delimit file extensions on your static resources.)

You write: "website.com/info.html?page=12 should show: website.com/info/12 ...
That does not really make much sense looking at rewriting URLs. Certainly you can redirect such URL, but that still shows the first URL before the redirection occurs. You need to understand that rewriting works on incoming requests. It does not somehow alter outgoing responses. Tools for that do exist, but I doubt that makes sense in your case. Instead you should take care that you application logic does not hand out that longer URL in the first place, but the one you actually want to use.
Redirecting requests to /info/ to /info certainly is possible, though it would be trivial to simply skip the redirection and directly deliver the expected response. As you like. Note that this also might be conflicting with other settings in your setup I know nothing about. So you will have to experiment a bit with that.
Anyway, this would be a starting point for you to externally redirect such a URL when requested . And to internally rewrite an incoming request to that shorter URL as desired:
RewriteEngine on

# externally redirect https://example.com/info.html?page=12
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=12$
RewriteRule ^/?info\.html$ /info/12 [R=301,L,QSD]

# externally redirect https://example.com/info.html
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^/?info\.html$ /info [R=301,L]

# optional: externally redirect https://example.com/info/
RewriteRule ^/?info/$ /info [R=301,L]

# internally rewrite requests to https://example.com/info/12
RewriteRule ^/?info/12/?$ /info.html?page=12 [L]
# internally rewrite requests to https://example.com/info
RewriteRule ^/?info/?$ /info.html [L]

Obviously you can implement that in a more general way:
RewriteEngine on

# externally redirect https://example.com/info.html?page=<any number>
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=(\d+)$
RewriteRule ^/?info\.html$ /info/%1 [R=301,L,QSD]

# externally redirect https://example.com/info.html
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^/?info\.html$ /info [R=301,L]

# optional: externally redirect https://example.com/info/
RewriteRule ^/?info/$ /info [R=301,L]

# internally rewrite requests to https://example.com/info/<any number>
RewriteRule ^/?info/(\d+)/?$ /info.html?page=$1 [L]
# internally rewrite requests to https://example.com/info
RewriteRule ^/?info/?$ /info.html [L]

You can implement those rules in the central http server's host configuration. That is the preferred place for such rules for various reasons. If you do not have access to that (read: if you are using a cheap web space provider) you can instead use a distributed configuration file (typically called ".htaccess"). For that you need to take care that such file is located in the folder configured as DocumentRoot inside your http host, that the file is readable by the http server process and that you enabled the interpretation of such rules in such files by means of the AllowOverride directive (see the documentation for details on that).

I would start by redirecting all the .html extensions to not show it in the URL.
Then if it has a number after it you can redirect page=number
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301] 

#redirect /number to ?page=number
RewriteRule ^info/([0-9]+)$ /info?page=$1 [L]



The conditions on the first rule will prevent the redirect from happening because /info.html is a physical file. You are missing .html in the substitution string on the 2nd rule. But this will otherwise result in a redirect loop. And what about requests for /info.html?page=12 and /info/?
